# How to debug an iOS app crash at launch time, breakpoint only in assembly file

Tags: ios, debugging, assembly, crash, grand-central-dispatch

I'am facing an issue with an app currently in development.
The problem is that the App crash at launch time when it was in background for a while, and only in that case.
Launching the app while it was killed doesn't lead to crash, from debugger or from phone.
Launching the app while it was in background for about 5-10 min doesn't lead to crash, while debugging or not.
Launching the app while in backgorund for about 15-20 min lead to a crash. Using debugger and breakpoint on exception gave me this file :

```
libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_assert_queue_fail:
0x349c6ce4:  push   {r4, r5, r7, lr}
0x349c6ce6:  add    r7, sp, #0x8
0x349c6ce8:  sub    sp, #0xc
0x349c6cea:  movw   r5, #0x7810
0x349c6cee:  mov    r4, r0
0x349c6cf0:  movt   r5, #0x1
0x349c6cf4:  movw   r12, #0x7af0
0x349c6cf8:  movt   r12, #0x1
0x349c6cfc:  movw   r9, #0x7a83
0x349c6d00:  movt   r9, #0x1
0x349c6d04:  ldr    r0, [r4, #0x48]
0x349c6d06:  movw   r2, #0x7a93
0x349c6d0a:  movt   r2, #0x1
0x349c6d0e:  movw   r3, #0x7af5
0x349c6d12:  movt   r3, #0x1
0x349c6d16:  add    r5, pc
0x349c6d18:  cmp    r0, #0x0
0x349c6d1a:  it     ne
0x349c6d1c:  movne  r5, r0
0x349c6d1e:  add    r12, pc
0x349c6d20:  add    r9, pc
0x349c6d22:  add    r3, pc
0x349c6d24:  cmp    r1, #0x0
0x349c6d26:  add    r2, pc
0x349c6d28:  strd   r4, r5, [sp]
0x349c6d2c:  it     ne
0x349c6d2e:  movne  r3, r12
0x349c6d30:  add    r0, sp, #0x8
0x349c6d32:  mov    r1, r9
0x349c6d34:  blx    0x349dda4c                ; symbol stub for: -[OS_object retainWeakReference]
0x349c6d38:  movw   r0, #0x7ae0
0x349c6d3c:  movt   r0, #0x1
0x349c6d40:  ldr    r1, [sp, #0x8]
0x349c6d42:  add    r0, pc
0x349c6d44:  bl     0x349c65cc                ; _dispatch_log
0x349c6d48:  trap   
0x349c6d4a:  nop
```

The debugger break on the trap line, just before the nop at the end with :

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
```

I can't find any clue on how to debug this.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT : here is a crash log with the stacktrace (I replaced my device name with DeviceName and the app name and my company name with com.company.myAppName) :

```
Sep 22 11:36:31 DeviceName locationd[63] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Sep 22 11:36:31 DeviceName myAppName[6750] <Warning>: *** Assertion failure in -[UIFetchContentInBackgroundAction sendResponse:], /SourceCache/BaseBoard/BaseBoard-97/BaseBoard/BSAction.m:221
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName myAppName[6750] <Notice>: BUG in client of libdispatch: Assertion failed: Block was run on an unexpected queue
    Expected queue: 0x0x3713cd40[com.apple.main-thread]
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 6750
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName diagnosticd[5999] <Error>: error evaluating process info - pid: 6750, punique: 6750
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process myAppName[6750]
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName SpringBoard[2836] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName wifid[68] <Notice>: WiFi:[433071392.290519]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: lockdownd networkd assistantd 
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.company.myAppName[0x3ff0][6750]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new logs.
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Could not save crash report to disk!
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName SpringBoard[2836] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.company.myAppName[0x3ff0]' crashed.
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName assertiond[57] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x145437b0; com.company.myAppName; pid: 6750> to 2, priority: No such process
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName assertiond[57] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x145437b0; com.company.myAppName; pid: 6750> to 4096, priority: No such process
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Incident Identifier: DF8D30C9-4F46-43CB-B192-323E819180A6
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: CrashReporter Key:   a93a18a1167cbedc4b3623154bd083fdd7770808
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Process:             myAppName [6750]
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DE60F941-317E-49C2-95EA-0F152A117C16/myAppName.app/myAppName
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName UserEventAgent[17] <Warning>: id=com.company.myAppName pid=6750, state=0
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName backboardd[56] <Warning>: Unable to bootstrap_look_up port with name com.company.myAppName.gsEvents: unknown error code (1102)
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Identifier:          myAppName
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Version:             ???
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Date/Time:           2014-09-22 11:36:32.054 +0200
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Launch Time:         2014-09-22 11:25:29.726 +0200
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: OS Version:          iOS 8.0 (12A365)
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Report Version:      105
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Triggered by Thread:  0
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Last Exception Backtrace:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: (0x26db3e3a 0x34461c86 0x26db3d10 0x27a845aa 0x2b8bf8c8 0x349c8b64 0x2b8bf832 0x2a7c7ba8 0x349c18c6 0x349c18b2 0x349c50ba 0x26d79be4 0x26d782e4 0x26cc661c 0x26cc642e 0x2e0740a4 0x2a2b0804 0xcee48 0x349e1aaa)
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 0 Crashed:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c6d48 0x349c0000 + 27976
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c4be4 0x349c0000 + 19428
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   FrontBoardServices                0x2d4e7830 0x2d4df000 + 34864
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 3   FrontBoardServices                0x2d4f40e6 0x2d4df000 + 86246
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName SpringBoard[2836] <Warning>: Unable to deliver -[UIRemoteApplication showTopMostMiniAlertWithSynchronizationPort:] message to port 0: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                    0x26d7a5b2 0x26cae000 + 837042
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                    0x26d79874 0x26cae000 + 833652
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 6   CoreFoundation                    0x26d77ff6 0x26cae000 + 827382
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 7   CoreFoundation                    0x26cc661c 0x26cae000 + 99868
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 8   CoreFoundation                    0x26cc642e 0x26cae000 + 99374
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 9   myAppName                         0x00177f72 0x4f000 + 1216370
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 10  CoreFoundation                    0x26db416c 0x26cae000 + 1073516
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 11  libobjc.A.dylib                   0x34461f10 0x3445b000 + 28432
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 12  libc++abi.dylib                   0x33d9ade0 0x33d83000 + 97760
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 13  libc++abi.dylib                   0x33d9a5a4 0x33d83000 + 95652
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName locationd[63] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 14  libobjc.A.dylib                   0x34461d5a 0x3445b000 + 27994
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 15  CoreFoundation                    0x26db3d10 0x26cae000 + 1072400
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 16  Foundation                        0x27a845aa 0x279f2000 + 599466
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 17  BaseBoard                         0x2b8bf8c8 0x2b89b000 + 149704
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 18  libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c8b64 0x349c0000 + 35684
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 19  BaseBoard                         0x2b8bf832 0x2b89b000 + 149554
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 20  UIKit                             0x2a7c7ba8 0x2a242000 + 5790632
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 21  libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c18c8 0x349c0000 + 6344
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 22  libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c18b4 0x349c0000 + 6324
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 23  libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c50ba 0x349c0000 + 20666
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 24  CoreFoundation                    0x26d79be4 0x26cae000 + 834532
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 25  CoreFoundation                    0x26d782e4 0x26cae000 + 828132
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 26  CoreFoundation                    0x26cc661c 0x26cae000 + 99868
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 27  CoreFoundation                    0x26cc642e 0x26cae000 + 99374
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 28  GraphicsServices                  0x2e0740a4 0x2e06b000 + 37028
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 29  UIKit                             0x2a2b0804 0x2a242000 + 452612
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 30  myAppName                         0x000cee48 0x4f000 + 523848
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 31  libdyld.dylib                     0x349e1aac 0x349e0000 + 6828
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 1:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34a942a0 0x34a93000 + 4768
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x349cd9fc 0x349c0000 + 55804
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c331e 0x349c0000 + 13086
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 2 name:  GAIThread  Dispatch queue: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x15582b60
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 2:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa9388 0x34a93000 + 91016
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x347e4164 0x3474b000 + 627044
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x3479334a 0x3474b000 + 295754
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 3   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x347d2544 0x3474b000 + 554308
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 4   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x347d1e54 0x3474b000 + 552532
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 5   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x34792f8e 0x3474b000 + 294798
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 6   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x34787c72 0x3474b000 + 248946
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 7   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x347657dc 0x3474b000 + 108508
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 8   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x34783f10 0x3474b000 + 233232
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 9   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x34778ed6 0x3474b000 + 188118
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 10  CoreData                          0x26ab7ab8 0x26aa2000 + 88760
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 11  CoreData                          0x26af0d92 0x26aa2000 + 322962
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 12  CoreData                          0x26b87110 0x26aa2000 + 938256
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 13  CoreData                          0x26b6c3ac 0x26aa2000 + 828332
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 14  CoreData                          0x26b717c8 0x26aa2000 + 849864
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 15  libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c18b4 0x349c0000 + 6324
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 16  libdispatch.dylib                 0x349c8b64 0x349c0000 + 35684
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 17  CoreData                          0x26b65302 0x26aa2000 + 799490
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 18  CoreData                          0x26b6bf9a 0x26aa2000 + 827290
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 19  CoreData                          0x26b3d5be 0x26aa2000 + 636350
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 20  myAppName                         0x0017312c 0x4f000 + 1196332
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 21  myAppName                         0x00171c46 0x4f000 + 1190982
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 22  myAppName                         0x00172fe2 0x4f000 + 1196002
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 23  myAppName                         0x0017d77e 0x4f000 + 1238910
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 24  myAppName                         0x0017e9ee 0x4f000 + 1243630
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 25  myAppName                         0x0017e7ec 0x4f000 + 1243116
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 26  Foundation                        0x27ac359a 0x279f2000 + 857498
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 27  CoreFoundation                    0x26d7a58c 0x26cae000 + 837004
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 28  CoreFoundation                    0x26d7999a 0x26cae000 + 833946
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 29  CoreFoundation                    0x26d78000 0x26cae000 + 827392
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 30  CoreFoundation                    0x26cc661c 0x26cae000 + 99868
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 31  CoreFoundation                    0x26cc642e 0x26cae000 + 99374
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 32  Foundation                        0x279fe428 0x279f2000 + 50216
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 33  Foundation                        0x27a4c8e8 0x279f2000 + 370920
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 34  myAppName                         0x0016f678 0x4f000 + 1181304
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 35  Foundation                        0x27ac3386 0x279f2000 + 856966
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 36  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e90 0x34b22000 + 11920
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 37  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e02 0x34b22000 + 11778
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 38  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b8c 0x34b22000 + 2956
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 3:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa7b38 0x34a93000 + 84792
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b243f4 0x34b22000 + 9204
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b252d8 0x34b22000 + 13016
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 3   Foundation                        0x27a48f62 0x279f2000 + 356194
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 4   myAppName                         0x0011f036 0x4f000 + 852022
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 5   Foundation                        0x27ac3386 0x279f2000 + 856966
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e90 0x34b22000 + 11920
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e02 0x34b22000 + 11778
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b8c 0x34b22000 + 2956
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 4:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa89cc 0x34a93000 + 88524
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22ea8 0x34b22000 + 3752
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b80 0x34b22000 + 2944
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 5 name:  PF_AFNetworking
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 5:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34a944f0 0x34a93000 + 5360
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34a942e4 0x34a93000 + 4836
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                    0x26d79b4e 0x26cae000 + 834382
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                    0x26d780f4 0x26cae000 + 827636
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                    0x26cc661c 0x26cae000 + 99868
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                    0x26cc642e 0x26cae000 + 99374
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 6   Foundation                        0x279fe428 0x279f2000 + 50216
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 7   Foundation                        0x27a4c8e8 0x279f2000 + 370920
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 8   myAppName                         0x001317ee 0x4f000 + 927726
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 9   Foundation                        0x27ac3386 0x279f2000 + 856966
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e90 0x34b22000 + 11920
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e02 0x34b22000 + 11778
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b8c 0x34b22000 + 2956
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 6:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34a944f0 0x34a93000 + 5360
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34a942e4 0x34a93000 + 4836
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                    0x26d79b4e 0x26cae000 + 834382
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                    0x26d780f4 0x26cae000 + 827636
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                    0x26cc661c 0x26cae000 + 99868
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                    0x26cc642e 0x26cae000 + 99374
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 6   CFNetwork                         0x2687f3da 0x26803000 + 508890
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 7   Foundation                        0x27ac3386 0x279f2000 + 856966
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e90 0x34b22000 + 11920
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e02 0x34b22000 + 11778
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b8c 0x34b22000 + 2956
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 7:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa808c 0x34a93000 + 86156
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   CoreFoundation                    0x26d7e31a 0x26cae000 + 852762
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e90 0x34b22000 + 11920
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b24e02 0x34b22000 + 11778
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b8c 0x34b22000 + 2956
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 8:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa89cc 0x34a93000 + 88524
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22ea8 0x34b22000 + 3752
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b80 0x34b22000 + 2944
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 9:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa89cc 0x34a93000 + 88524
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22ea8 0x34b22000 + 3752
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b80 0x34b22000 + 2944
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 10:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa89cc 0x34a93000 + 88524
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22ea8 0x34b22000 + 3752
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b80 0x34b22000 + 2944
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 11:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa89cc 0x34a93000 + 88524
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22ea8 0x34b22000 + 3752
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b80 0x34b22000 + 2944
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 12:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x34aa89cc 0x34a93000 + 88524
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22ea8 0x34b22000 + 3752
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x34b22b80 0x34b22000 + 2944
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>:     r0: 0x0056c500    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x156a7a00      r3: 0x00000fff
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>:     r4: 0x3713cd40    r5: 0x349de338      r6: 0x352bfca8      r7: 0x005622e8
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>:     r8: 0x155c4610    r9: 0x156a8000     r10: 0x155c4610     r11: 0x156cb5f0
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>:     ip: 0x37154124    sp: 0x005622d4      lr: 0x349c6d49      pc: 0x349c6d48
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>:   cpsr: 0x60000030
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: Binary Images:
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0x4f000 - 0x2eefff myAppName armv7  <8d48834e6e563ba08bd970b675b2c2b1> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DE60F941-317E-49C2-95EA-0F152A117C16/myAppName.app/myAppName
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0x1fed6000 - 0x1fef9fff dyld armv7s  <fd3fef9c43c9382e8e46d5d59fb52f86> /usr/lib/dyld
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0x25852000 - 0x259befff AVFoundation armv7s  <291c7a621b65396491697e7a7f728b16> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
Sep 22 11:36:32 DeviceName ReportCrash[6766] <Error>: 0x259bf000 - 0x25a1dfff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <1b452a7a75513cf9aa82e59feb7eef33> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
A lot of lines like the previous one
```

Comment: The stacktrace is most important.

Comment: Thnaks I added the crash log with the Last Exception Backtrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this error messages. It seems an assertion check was failed in iOS SDK.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIFetchContentInBackgroundAction sendResponse:], /SourceCache/BaseBoard/BaseBoard-97/BaseBoard/BSAction.m:221
BUG in client of libdispatch: Assertion failed: Block was run on an unexpected queue
Expected queue: 0x0x3713cd40[com.apple.main-thread]
```

The assertion did check that the specified block would run on the right dispatch queue. From the assertion message and the stack trace, `-[UIFetchContentInBackgroundAction sendResponse:]` uses [dispatch_assert_queue](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.92.1/src/queue.c) to check that the application code are using the main queue for the block properly.

So you'd better check your background fetch code that should use the main queue, but your code is using global queue, serial queue or concurrent queue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was that the completion handler was called twice subsequently

Code with issue

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    if(condition)
    {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Fix

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    if(condition)
    {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }
    else //fix
    {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }
}
```

Please make sure you are not making such a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue depicted by @Kazuki Sakamoto:

```
2014-10-16 01:37:05.284 musiXmatch[1589:400275] *** Assertion failure in -`[UIFetchContentInBackgroundAction sendResponse:], /SourceCache/BaseBoard/BaseBoard-97/BaseBoard/BSAction.m:221`
```

Adding a

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

Fixed the issue!

Comment: I finally figured out that I wasn't properly calling the completion handler and worse than that, the app sometimes exceeded the allowed times to run in background.