# iOS APP Crash For Unknown Log

Tags: ios, crash

The following is the crash log I get.But,I don't konw what caused this crash.I'm using 7.2.1 version of Xcode and iOS 9.2.1,device is a iPod touch.I call a third SDK's init method,then the app crashed.Thanks

The init method:

```
[m_SoHaSDKClass initWithGameDelegate:self application:application];
```

The device log:

```
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: UNNotificationRegistrarConnectionListener connection invalidated
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:vn.sohagame.sg69[0x1782][11313]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.51.1
    [11312] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [2c30/0f07]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x1f2189ec, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.51.1
    [11312] <Warning>: Exiting.
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 gputoolsd[11309] <Notice>: schedule invalidation <DYTransport 0x176862b0, error: explicit invalidation (6)>
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 gputoolsd[11309] <Notice>: schedule invalidation <DYTransport 0x17617560, error: lost transport connection (31)>
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 gputoolsd[11309] <Notice>: terminating daemon 0x17524f20
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 11313: No such process
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 11313: No such process
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 11313: No such process
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:vn.sohagame.sg69[0x581f]) <Error>: The DisableASLR key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:vn.sohagame.sg69[0x1782]' exited voluntarily.
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:vn.sohagame.sg69[0x581f]': No such process (err 3)
Mar 10 11:51:27 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1d380bc0; vn.sohagame.sg69; pid: -1>
Mar 10 11:51:28 ceshi-9 UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 45831112213045: id=vn.sohagame.sg69 pid=11313, state=0
Mar 10 11:51:28 ceshi-9 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:vn.sohagame.sg69[0x581f]' exited voluntarily.
```

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992205/how-to-debug-an-ios-app-crash-at-launch-time-breakpoint-only-in-assembly-file

Comment: Just need more informations, 
Post some code or at least tell us how you tried to solve this problem

Comment: @maddy Can you tell me what caused the crash form these log?

Comment: @DinhNhat I called the third SDK's init method,then the app crashed.[m_SoHaSDKClass initWithGameDelegate:self application:application];

Comment: @DinhNhat I added try catch block around this method,but it caught nothing.Xcode didn't show any information,it likes called 'exit(0)'.

Comment: Enable NSZoombie and check if you go more informations.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20515768/2594699

Comment: @DinhNhat It doesn't work.But I created a new project without the other res,then not crash.And, I called the init method in same way.